# Why considering all features does not replicate considering the combination of all pairs of features in DBSCAN algorithm?

Tags: dbscan

I was trying to see, in DBSCAN algorithm, the number of noise points I get considering all n features resembles the combination of all nC2 features or not?

I am using the following terminologies:
Suppose, n is the number of features.
**1. Overall model:** Model that takes all the features (n) into account
**2. Combine model:** Model that considers the combination of all pair of features (all nC2 combinations). If a sample is considered as a noise point in any of the combined model, then the point is labeled as abnormal.
**3. Abnormal:** If a sample is noise point then it is considered to be abnormal
**4. Normal:** Any point other than abnormal

To make it more clear, suppose I have 3 features: f1,f2,f3. The overall model considers all 3 features while clustering. The combination model uses 3 models (f1,f2) , (f2,f3) and (f1,f3). If any of these 3 models label a sample as noise, then the point is considered to be "Abnormal"; otherwise, it is "Normal".

My assumption was that the combination model will give me the same number of noise points as the overall one, but it is giving less noise points. The point that is considered as a noise point in the combined model, is also labeled as noise point in overall model.

Although I am using the same hyperparameters, why it is not giving me the same solution?

Are there any problem with my implementation?
My python code segment:

```
### libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def func(data_file,eps,minPts, number_of_features):    
    print("For ", str(number_of_features)," features: ")

    ### loading dataset
    dataset = pd.read_csv(data_file)

    ### tracking label of all combination of feature relation considering 2 at a time
    labels_arr=[]

    ### checking all combination of feature relation considering 2 at a time using dbscan algorithm
    for i in range(number_of_features-1):
        for j in range(i+1,number_of_features):
            features = dataset.iloc[0:1000, np.r_[ [i,j] ]].values
            db = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=minPts).fit(features)
            labels = db.labels_
            labels_arr.append(labels)

    ### counting number of positive (and noise) samples in combined model    
    cnt=0
    comb_model=[]
    comb_abnormal_cnt=[]
    for j in range(len(labels)):
        flg=0
        abnormal_cnt=0
        for i in range(len(labels_arr)):
            # if any data point is noise for any model, that data point is considered noise for the propose model
            if labels_arr[i][j]==-1:
                abnormal_cnt+=1
                flg=-1
                #print(j,i)
        comb_abnormal_cnt.append(abnormal_cnt)
        if flg==0:
            cnt+=1
            comb_model.append("Normal")
        else:
            comb_model.append("Abnormal")        
    print("Number of positives in combined model",cnt)


    ### counting number of positive (and noise) samples in overall model    
    new_model=[]
    features = dataset.iloc[0:1000, 0:number_of_features].values
    db = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=minPts).fit(features)
    labels = db.labels_
    cnt=0
    for val in labels:
        if val==-1:
            new_model.append("Abnormal")
        else:
            new_model.append("Normal")
            cnt+=1
    print("Number of positives in overall model",cnt)

    ### checking matches in both model    
    cnt=0
    for i in range(len(new_model)):
        if new_model[i]==comb_model[i]:
            cnt+=1
    print("Number of matches in both",cnt)


func("test.csv",.2,5,3)
func("test.csv",1,3,23)
```

The output of this code looks something like this

```
For  3  features: 
Number of positives in combined model 995
Number of positives in overall model 983
Number of matches in both 988
For  23  features: 
Number of positives in combined model 840
Number of positives in overall model 528
Number of matches in both 688
```

Could you help me with the mathematical foundation of the problem I have stated?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare epsilon across different subspaces. I am even surprised the results do not diverge more than that.

Beware that DBSCAN does *not* focus on reliably detecting ano alies - use an anomaly detection method instead. Noise points in DBSCAN are those that do not fit the cluster well, but background noise is not always anomalous, it can be extremely common.